# Check if an element has array name, and extract info

Tags: jquery, arrays

Lets say I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" name="action[5][3]">
```

How do I check to see if the input name is "action" considering it also includes keys? I.e.:

```
if (hasArrayName($(this).attr('name'), 'action') == true) {
    console.log('element is an action');
}
```

Also, how do I extract each bit of information from the name? I want to map these 3 pieces of information out like so:

```
var array_name = 'action';
var index_1 = '5';
var index_2 = '3';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `str.indexOf('action')`

Comment: `if ($(this).attr('name').indexOf('action') > -1)` worked awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding a susbtring in a string use `indexOf`:

```
console.log( $(this).attr('name').indexOf('action') );
```

For finding parts of `name` you can use regexp and `exec` for example:

```
console.log( /(action)\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/.exec('action[2][5]') );
// ["action[2][5]", "action", "2", "5"]
```